# 400 Error when doing Spring Rest Post with subclass object

Tags: java, spring, junit

I am getting 
400 Error when doing Spring Rest Post from subclass object to super class reference !!

**jUnit Test :-- (It fails)**

```
SubClass subClassObj = new SubClass();
restTemplate.postForObject(restURL, subClassObj, SubClass.class);
```

**spring controller method :--**

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value =
 "/post-subclass-obj", headers = "Accept=application/json") 

public @ResponseBody SuperClass postSubClassObj(@RequestBody SuperClass
 superClassObj) { 

        return superClassObj;
}
```

**jUnit Test :-- (It works)**

```
SuperClass superClassObj = new SuperClass();
restTemplate.postForObject(restURL, superClassObj, SubClass.class);
```

Thanks in Advance !!

Comment: Let's see your `SuperClass` and your `SubClass`.

Comment: Any solution to this problem? Can we pass Super class type in @RequestBody? ... I am getting exactly the same issue